# How to fix an addition namespace attribute after executes a query?

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

i have the following xml file.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  xmlns:ns="http://example.com/ns">
  <soapenv:Header xmlns:ns1="http://www.ns1.com"/>
   <soapenv:Body>
     <ns:request>
      <ns:customer>
       <ns:id>123</ns:id>
       <ns:name type="NCHZ">John Brown</ns:name>
      </ns:customer>
     </ns:request>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

when i get `<ns:request>` element using the following **xquery/xpath**.

```
declare namespace soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"; declare namespace ns="http://example.com/ns"; //soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/ns:request
```

the result will be

```
<ns:request xmlns:ns="http://example.com/ns" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <ns:customer>
        <ns:id>123</ns:id>
        <ns:name type="NCHZ">John Brown</ns:name>
    </ns:customer>
</ns:request>
```

why `xmlns:ns="http://example.com/ns" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"` attribute in the `<ns:request>` element is added although it doesn't exist on the main xml file ? and how to fix it?

Comment: Sure those namespace declarations exist in the XML input, they are declared on the root element and that way are in scope for descendant element and of course if you select a descendant and serialize it the serializer has to add the namespace declaration. So what output instead do you expect? How do you want to output an element named `ns:request` without declaring its namespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get rid of the in-scope but unused namespace `xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"` by using `declare copy-namespaces no-preserve` and a document constructor in XQuery e.g.

```
declare copy-namespaces no-preserve, no-inherit;

declare namespace soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"; 
declare namespace ns="http://example.com/ns"; 

document {
//soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/ns:request
}
```

https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWcDMes

so that way the result would be

```
<ns:request xmlns:ns="http://example.com/ns">
  <ns:customer>
   <ns:id>123</ns:id>
   <ns:name type="NCHZ">John Brown</ns:name>
  </ns:customer>
 </ns:request>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand the way namespaces work in the XDM data model. Every element node has a set of in-scope namespaces (prefix-uri) bindings, which are obtained by looking at all the namespace declarations in ancestor elements. When an element node is serialized, all the in-scope namespaces are serialized as namespace declaration attributes, because the processor doesn't know which of them are needed and which aren't.

In your case one of the namespaces (ns) is needed (because it's used in element names) while the other one isn't (it isn't used anywhere).

In XSLT (2.0+) you can get rid of unused namespaces using `<xsl:copy>` with `copy-namespaces='no'`. But XPath always gives you the input nodes unchanged: so if an element has two in-scope namespaces in the input, it will still have two in-scope namespaces in the output, and these will be visible when the element is serialized.